# É possível abrir um arquivo com o IDLE a partir to terminal?

Tags: python

O IDLE permite abrir um arquivo para escrever os nossos programas (carregando CRTL + N, se não me engano), mas, devido a um problema com o IDLE do Python 3.4.1 ou 3.4.0, eu não posso usá-lo corretamente. Posso usar o Python só através do terminal.

É possível abrir um arquivo com o IDLE a partir to terminal?

Comment: A pergunta era como abrir/criar um arquivo no IDLE a partir do terminal? Editei e respondi considerando que era.

Comment: Ok Rinzler, obrigado por esclarecer. Espero que a pergunta e as respostas ajudem mais alguém!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode abrir qualquer arquivo (inclusive um novo, já dando um nome para ele), simplesmente digitando no terminal:

```
idle arquivo.py
```

Answer (score 4):

O interpretador Python só roda programas Python, ele não vem com uma interface de edição embutida. O que você pode fazer é usar um editor de texto para escrever seu programa (qualquer um menos o Word serve: Notepad++, Scite, Gedit, Emacs, Vim, etc...) e depois passar o arquivo que você criou para o interpretador python usandl a linha de comando.

Se você criar um arquivo meuprograma.py você pode rodar ele no terminal usando

```
python meuprograma.py
```

Se você quiser carregar o seu programa dentro de um loop interativo do Python você pode usar a flag -i

```
python -i meuprograma.py
```